# How do I fix this Virtualbox Error on Ubuntu start up?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 using Virtualbox.

I did the following after the installation was completed:

1. Mounted the Virtualbox Guest Additions CD
2. Installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions software
3. Performed updates using the built in 'Software Updater' program
4. Performed updates to the system using the following commands:

`apt-get -y update
 apt-get -y dist-upgrade
 apt-get -y upgrade`

However, now after I turn the VM on, I get the following message:

`VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service, rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Is the guest still accessible?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Do you mean, the Guest CD? No, I ejected it after install of its software.

Comment: From a quick Google search, it seems that you installed the wrong CD, but apparently some users were able to resolve the issue by running it again.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yeah, I found those awesome before posting this question, however, that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a modules problem - possibly the host modules are not loaded

On my system the following are loaded:

```
vboxnetflt
vboxnetadp
vboxpci
vboxdrv
```

Also, this might help: https://superuser.com/questions/545542/failed-to-connect-to-the-virtualbox-kernel-service